# What is .gr file format?

Tags: graph, file-format, adjacency-list

I am confused between a .gr file and an adjacency list representation of graph.
How does the data in .gr file looks like? Is it in adjacency list form or there is some other format in which the data is displayed in .gr file?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Tab-delimited graph format. A simple text format containing two columns of numbers separated by a single space or tab.  The first number is the base position; the second number is the score.