# How can we convert a .gr graph file to a .cm graph file?

Tags: graph-theory, file-extension

I was working on a graph file with `.gr` extension and came across a relevant dataset with `.cm` extension. My code is compatible with `.gr` extension but I wish to use `.cm` dataset.

Problem:
I do not understand the format in which data is represented and thus cannot parse it. In some files there is even text instead of numbers.

The dataset represents protein molecules.

Question:
How to parse `.cm` file into `.gr` file and how is data represented in `.cm` file?

This is the content of one of the `.cm` graph file describing a graph:

```
5
8
0
1
7
9
-1  -1  -1  1   
1   -1  -1  
1   -1  
1
```

Now how to figure out the number of nodes and the edges present in this graph.

This is the content of a `.gr` file extension.

```
p cep 4 3
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Comment: Hard to say.  the gr format appears to be for charts or plots, not for graphs with nodes and edges ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/30669415/16582 )  I can't find a mention of cm file format.

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you asking about graphs ( i.e. plots or charts ) or graph-theory ( nodes and edges )

Comment: @ravenspoint the question pertains to graph theory

Comment: @ravenspoint we are working on a biological dataset and we have both .gr and .cm dataset. .cm dataset is more useful to us but we do not understand the representation, nor can we find any information online regarding that.  https://bio.informatik.uni-jena.de/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/samples_v_100to2000_k_025vto25v.zip --> LINK to the dataset

Comment: I have fixed your tag.  If you put the details in your question, I will rescind the close vote.

Comment: close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cm file, which is short for cluster matrix file, the first number denotes the total number of nodes.

The following n lines denote the labels (hence the string) of the nodes.

The matrix then denotes the cost to add an edge between two nodes. Note that the first cell (row=0, column=0) in the matrix denote that the cost to add edge between node n and node n-1. The second cell (row=0, column=1) in the matrix denote the cost to add edge between node n and node n-2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
-1  -1  -1  1   
1   -1  -1  
1   -1  
1
```

This looks like it might be describing a 4 node graph.

but this

```
5
8
0
1
7
9
```

looks like something to do with a graph of 6 nodes.

Comment: The gr file and cm file belong to different graphs and there is no relationship between them... We just uploaded them to give an idea about how each is represented

Comment: In gr file clearly in the first line 4 represents no of nodes and 3 represents no of edges. And rest of lines denote the edgeset. In cm file... I believe the lower matrix is edge matrix but i don't understand anything above the upper triangular matrix.